# Какой сонет Бальмонт посвятил буквам, исключенным из алфавита при реформе орфографии?

Tags: старая-орфография

Прочитала в одной статье, что Бальмонт посвятил уничтоженным буквам пламенный сонет. Искала сонет по похожим названиям и не нашла. Кто-нибудь знает, что это за сонет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Защита слов(а).](http://eprints.gla.ac.uk/151991/1/151991.pdf)* Сонет Бальмонта сам по себе является ярким
образцом апологии старой азбуки:

**Гонимымъ**

Защита слова Ъ, о, твердый знакъ,

Без Ъ все слово – пьяный, обнаженный.

Разумный стражъ, вѣками подкѣрпленный,

Домъ безъ замка не можетъ быть никакъ.

Безъ Ъ все слово – срѣзанное “Квакъ!”,

Безхвостый конь, и песъ, хвоста лишенный.

Без Ъ лишь коммунистъ умалишенный

Все буквы грудитъ в общiй кавардакъ.

Изменчиваго Е расцвѣтъ и скрѣпа,

Лицо въ лицо, глядитъ на честныхъ Ѣ

Того лишь варваръ не сумѣлъ понять.

Взамѣнъ Ѳ два круга Ф нелѣпо.

I съ точкой, тонкiй жезликъ, наконецъ,

Двойною палкой пишетъ лишь слѣпецъ.